# Could someone please translate this small writting for me? (Characters identified: 林盾)

Tags: translation, character-identification

It's very difficult to make out and I don't know for sure if it's Chinese (at least it should be) or some other eastern language. Having it translated to english would really help me out since I need to know exactly what it says.

[image]

Having a hard time trying translate it via online means. Any help is appreciated. It's some writting from a dust respirator (like a gas mask) on the front. Ordered from a chinese webstore. The picture is low quality since i had to zoom it in a lot.

Comment: I'd like to help you meanwhile I have to vote for closing because translation or text recognition is not within the scope of this website.

Comment: Thank you for informing me and sorry for going off topic. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out and wish you all the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says '林盾' - most likely a person's name where 林 (Lin, meaning 'forest') is the last name and 盾 (Dun, meaning 'shield') is the given name.

Comment: Since it's coming off a dust respirator, is there a possibility it could mean something like "wood shield" ... like a sawdust mask? Just a thought, I don't really know :)

Comment: @Ming, perhaps it's the name of the manufacturer. Any other word beside this 2 ?

Comment: Not really, no. Thank you all for your assistance.